# Download image in to local root storage with app name in Android > 6

Tags: android, download

I'm using below code for downloading the image and it download successfully but not showing in galary please help!!!

I have tried couple of examples none of them are working..

I have also tried the MediaScanner to scan the file and update the gallery

If anyone have links related this question please share

```
    class DownloadFileFromURL : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

     override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Void? {
        var count: Int
        try {
            val url = URL(getUrl())
            val conection: URLConnection = url.openConnection()
            conection.connect()
            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            val input: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192)

            val output: OutputStream?
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                val resolver: ContentResolver = activity?.contentResolver!!
                val contentValues = ContentValues()
                val name = System.currentTimeMillis()
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "$name.jpg")
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                val imageUri: Uri? = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
                output = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }!!
            } else {
                val imgFile = createImageFile()
                if (!imgFile.exists()) {
                    imgFile.createNewFile()
                }
                output = FileOutputStream(imgFile)
            }


            // Output stream to write file
            val data = ByteArray(1024)
            var total: Long = 0
            while (input.read(data).also { count = it } != -1) {
                total += count.toLong()
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count)
            }
            // flushing output
            output.flush()

            // closing streams
            output.close()
            input.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.message)
        }
        return null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        downloadComplete()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(Date())
        val storageDir: File = activity?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
        return File(
                storageDir, /* directory */
                "JPEG_${timeStamp}"+ /* prefix */
                ".jpg" /* suffix */

        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            mCurrentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your code does not work for Android Q?

Comment: it does work for android Q and even Android 7.0 works but it does not shown in gallary

Comment: Does it not show in gallery for Android Q?

Comment: It does but not showing on android 7

Comment: Then please update your question as that all should be clear from the beginning. I had to ask two times what happened.